# How to get Shodan API to return results?

Tags: shodan

I'm using a search filter in the shodan api endpoint **/shodan/host/search**. The problem is that the API returns a response indicating that there was a match for the filter but the matches array is empty as you can see in the screenshot. The documentation of the Shodan API also states that the matches array contains search results but why isn't it returning any results for me? I've checked my API usage limit and I have plenty of Search credits available.

[image]